# Stub to return different values

Tags: spock

Suppose I have a  method like this

```java
String getString()
```

I can vary easily stub that so that it return "test-string"

```groovy
def myStub = Stub(MyClass)
myStub.getString() >> "test-string"
```

Suppose, `getString()` is within a for loop. And in the loop I'd like it to return `"test-string-1"` the first time, `"test-string-2"` the second time, `"test-string-3"` the third time.

How would I do that?

Comment: Your short question contained two syntax errors which I fixed for you. Please give your questions some more love in the future, would you?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the [`>>>` notation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M3/all_in_one.html#_returning_sequences_of_values) in order to chain a fixed series of stub return values or use a [closure](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M3/all_in_one.html#_computing_return_values) if you want something more fancy/dynamic:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62974132

import spock.lang.Specification

class StubWithMultipleReturnValuesTest extends Specification {
  def "stub returns a fixed sequence of values"() {
    given:
    def underTest = Stub(UnderTest)
    underTest.getString() >>> ["test-string-1", "test-string-2", "test-string-3"]

    expect:
    underTest.getString() == "test-string-1"
    underTest.getString() == "test-string-2"
    underTest.getString() == "test-string-3"
    // As of now, always the last value is returned because
    // there are no more new ones in the stub definition
    underTest.getString() == "test-string-3"
  }

  def "stub calculates return value in a closure"() {
    given:
    def underTest = Stub(UnderTest)
    int counter = 0
    underTest.getString() >> { "test-string-${++counter}" }

    expect:
    underTest.getString() == "test-string-1"
    underTest.getString() == "test-string-2"
    underTest.getString() == "test-string-3"
    underTest.getString() == "test-string-4"
  }

  static class UnderTest {
    String getString() {
      "real result"
    }
  }
}
```